# how to show two different users location on a google map android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

How to show on google map when some one using my app & getting his/her current location, And i want show both location vice versa like Ola app example, user see different driver on his google map. Is i want to used Socket Connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On location changed, you can update user location on server and you have to fetch the location from server in continuous loop.

Comment: But it now showing me different user location when we both using the same app at same time. how can i achieve this.

Comment: you have to update your location on server and the other user have to fetch your location from server.

Comment: Please can you give me some more details so that i can get better idea, how to make it.

Comment: you have your location, now update this location with web service on server. other users will use another api to get locations from server and show on their map. this process will run continuously on location change.

Comment: Okay thanks i hope it will work. But can i use this on same api key which i get from google on create project.

Comment: @david yes, you can use same api key.

Comment: @david if it has solve your problem can you mark it correct answer.